# returnキーで生成したはずのtextfieldが画面に追加されない

Tags: swift, xcode, swift3, xcode8

`textFieldShouldReturn`を使って、`textfield`を新たに生成するコードを作りたいのですが、新しい`textfield`が画面(正確には、ポップアップ遷移先のビュー`AddTaskView`)に追加されません。どのようにすれば追加されるようになるでしょうか。
今までの`textfield`を含む配列`AllTF`の要素の数をタイトルとするボタン（`addAllTask`）には、新しく生成した`textfield`の分が反映されているので、生成はされているはずなのですが、、、、
なお、操作は全て、ポップアップで画面遷移した遷移先の`AddTaskViewController`で行われています。また、`TF1`や`addAllTask`、新しく追加したい`textfield`は全て`AddTaskView`上のものです。
以下、コードを掲載します。
回答して頂けたら幸いです。

```
import UIKit

class AddTaskViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate{

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        TF1.delegate = self
        addAllTask.setTitle("タスクを１項目追加", for: .normal)
        AllTF.append(TF1)
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    @IBOutlet weak var AddTaskView: UIView!

    @IBOutlet weak var addAllTask: UIButton!

    @IBOutlet weak var TF1: UITextField!

    var AllTF: [UITextField] = []


    var nextTF: UITextField!

    func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool
    {
        let numberOfTF = AllTF.count

        textField.resignFirstResponder()
        createNewTF(parameter: numberOfTF)
        return true
    }

    func createNewTF(parameter: Int)
    {
        let width = Int(TF1.frame.width)
        let height = Int(TF1.frame.height)
        let X = Int(TF1.frame.origin.x)
        let Y = Int(TF1.frame.origin.y) + (height + 10) * parameter

        nextTF = UITextField(frame: CGRect(x: X, y: Y, width: width, height: height))
        self.AddTaskView.addSubview(nextTF)
        AllTF.append(nextTF)
        nextTF.delegate = self

        addAllTask.setTitle("タスクを\(AllTF.count)項目追加", for: .normal)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Text Fieldは、新規に追加されているはずですね。コードから生成した`UITextField`のデフォルトが、枠なしのスタイルなので、追加されたように見えないだけではありませんか？

```
// var nextTF: UITextField! // 削除

func createNewTF(parameter: Int)
{
    let width = Int(TF1.frame.width)
    let height = Int(TF1.frame.height)
    let X = Int(TF1.frame.origin.x)
    let Y = Int(TF1.frame.origin.y) + (height + 10) * parameter

    let nextTF = UITextField(frame: CGRect(x: X, y: Y, width: width, height: height)) // 変更
    nextTF.borderStyle = TF1.borderStyle // 追加
    self.AddTaskView.addSubview(nextTF)
    AllTF.append(nextTF)
    nextTF.delegate = self

    addAllTask.setTitle("タスクを\(AllTF.count)項目追加", for: .normal)
}
```

新規作成したText Fieldのスタイルを、`TF1`と同じに指定することで、追加が目で確認できるよう、1行追加してみました。

なお、本題と直接関係ありませんが、`nextTF`をプロパティとする意味がわからないので、上のサンプルコードでは、ローカルな変数に変更してあります。

Comment: とても単純なミスでしたね・・・ありがとうございます。